# Prometheus/Grafana Legend visibility

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have a query which is working as expected, and I am showing by (Last *), as attached. But I am wondering if it is possible to hide the actual text within the legend for that value, specifically the "Last *:" and to just have it show the resulting number. I am unable to see an option on the right hand panel

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use table format: `Last *` will be placed in header of column.

Comment: I see what you mean @markalex, however it just neatly organises this data, rather than removing the word. I was hoping there would be a way to remove the word completely from the legend, as non-technical people will be consuming the information and, unfortunately I am asked what it is quite commonly.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to do so. IMO, table format should cause less questions. But you can try to add more columns to make it clearer. Something like `Total` or `Mean`